# Sum of all elements in CvArr with OpenCV C API

Tags: c, opencv

Using OpenCV's, **C** language based API, I need to calculate sum of all elements in an OpenCV array. I use the `sum`([1](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#sum)) method. Below is what I have tried.

```
/* rgb1 is an OpenCV array */
CvScalar cvSum( const CvArr* rgb1);
printf("%lf", CvScalar.val);
```

But I get compiler error as `error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token`.

Comment: So ... what's the error?

Comment: @ams updated my question, which shows the error

Comment: Does the `->` operator work instead of `.`?

Comment: @ams no same error, only . is replaced by ->

Comment: Then you need to read the manual and understand what `CvScalar` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'val' [is an array of `double`s](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvscalar#CvScalar). You need to access it via `val[0]`, and `printf` it using `%f`

You also have a bug. What you wrote in not valid C code.
It should be this:

```
CvScalar sum = cvSum(rgb1);
printf("%f", sum.val[0]);
```

or if you don't want the variable:

```
printf("%f", cvSum(rgb1).val[0]);
```

Comment: yes I have tried that way also like this: printf("%f", CvScalar.val[0]);  but still getting same error

Comment: Doh, can't believe I missed the typename-used-as-variable!